# Populate dropdownlist2 onSelectedIndexChange()event of dropdownlist1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display the **Category_Type_Item** in **dropdownlist2** when i choose the relevant **Category_Items** from **dropdownlist1** 
here is my pageload code that populate dropdownlist1:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Select Item First";


            //dropdown for categories
            String query3 = "SELECT * from tbl_Category  ";
            SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter(query3, conn);
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            da3.Fill(ds3);


            if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                DropDownList1.DataSource = ds3;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Category_Name";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Category_ID";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Values Not Found";
            }}
```

and here is onselectedindexchange code for populating dropdownlist2:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String query3 = "SELECT * from tbl_Category_type where Category_ID='"+DropDownList1.SelectedValue+"'  ";
        SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter(query3, conn);
        DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
        da3.Fill(ds3);


        if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            DropDownList2.DataSource = ds3;
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Category_type_Name";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Category_type_ID";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Values Not Found";
        }

    }
```

Why is this code not working, anyone please help me

Comment: Did you try setting `DataTable` as Datasource, ` DropDownList2.DataSource = ds3.Tables[0];` ?

Comment: No . But as far as i think dropdownlist2 is surely getting the source here, Problem is in the call for **onSelectedIndexChange()**

Comment: I solved it. I just added the **AutoPostBack='"True"** in my dropdownlist! and it solved the issue